# Laravel 5 REST API and Dashboard

Tags: php, laravel

Доброго времени суток. Вопрос таков я создал проект на Laravel 5 and Dingo REST API только для мобильных клиентов, хотел бы узнать можно в этом же проекте Laravel 5 сделать панель управления?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В чем собственно проблема? Вы можете сделать web-интерфейс для вашего приложения, отдельный от API